# Security time to live token in nodejs

Tags: node.js, algorithm, security, ttl

I have implemented in nodejs a security token for an API that communicates only over ajax requests.
Upon each request a security token is sent, if this token exists, a new one is generated and sent in the response via header.
If it does not exist, the response ends with a 403, this is if there are no login credentials passed.

The problem is when I start two requests at the same time (let's say *A* and *B*), both of them send the same security token, *A* ends before *B*, thus updating the token before *B*, therefore the token that was passed to *B* is in this case invalid, because it was invalidated by *A*.

How can I overcome this issue?
How can I reimplement it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a token that is built up of two parts: one shared between the client and the server and the other one based on some external parameter.
You don't even have to *renew* it.

As an example, imagine that client and server share a numeric token named `t` and they agree on that token during the first call (login, user creation, whatever you want).
When they create the token, they also set a counter `c` to `0` and create a couple `p = <t, c>` that is the *current* token (or better, the last seen).
They must never send the token or the counter explicitly in any request.

When the client wants to send a message to the server, steps are:

- Create the new value `v = t*c`
- Updated `p` as `<t,c+1>`
- Send the request using the generated token `v`

Each request will have an unique actual token.

To verify the token on the server, steps are:

- Compute a set of *accepted tokens* `aN` as it follows:

  - `a0 = v*(c-N/2)` (where `c' = (c-N/2)`)
  - `a1 = v*(c-N/2+1)`
  - ...
  - `aN = v*(c+N/2-1)`
- If there exists `aM` that is equal to the received token, then accept the request
- If the request has been accepted, update the counter server side accordingly if the `c'` used to create the chosen `aM` is greater than the current `c`

This way, concurrent requests are nicely handled and you don't have to renew the token explicitly.

Whenever a request fails, the client can decide to reset the shared token `t` and the counter `c` somehow with a dedicated endpoint.
The server can simply reject a request for which there doesn't exist a valid `aM` in the computed set and that's all.

Of course, you must be able to store those tokens somehow, somewhere.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I will try it!

Comment: @patentul You are welcome. Let me know if it fits your needs. Also note that is not necessarily bound to nodejs as a solution.